# Getting an error in Python library Installation

Tags: python, android

Am getting the following and trying to install a new library in **PyCharm**. I have never came across this error before. I have tried going to google for a solution, but I can't find any that helps. The error is below

```
Error loading package list:unknown protocol: c
```

Please I need help to finish a project am working on.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set up a proxy in PyCharm. Here is a similar issue with details on JetBrains Comunity site:

- [Error Loading Package List](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000450230-Error-Loading-Package-List)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't setup the proxy before. After your suggestion it worked. Sorry for the late reply.